# Which is the duplicate?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, exact-duplicates

[What is the plural of the word “index”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3123/10041) asked Sep 16 '10 [on this site].

[Indexes or Indices?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/61080/10041) asked Jun 16 '09, migrated from stackoverflow.com 3 hours ago.

Clearly these are duplicates of each other, but which should be closed as duplicate?

Comment: This should set the cat among the pigeons! By rights if we here at ELU have the bottle, we should start downvoting the top answer on the StackOverflow one, since our collective opinion as expressed on the ELU one is that it's *not* the correct answer!

Comment: I've added a comment to the accepted answer on the migrated question. Of course, right now it's hidden by default... :/

Comment: Also, I don't think a question this old and with so many votes should have been migrated. If someone realized that it's off-topic, they should have quietly closed it and deleted it, not passed on the problem to us.

Comment: Actually, I think it's a good call by @nohat to have merged it that way round. Not just because the SO one is older and has more votes - it's a [call to action](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60921) for ELU to show we're able and willing to stand up and have *our* votes count against the dweebs who **voted for the wrong answer**. Someone can just make a "non-edit" to bump it up every few days until our top answer really is top again! If we can't manage that we're a divided community, and pretty much a lost cause anyway.

Comment: I just deleted the top answer because its upvotes were, imho, unearned in a ELU context.

Answer (score 3):

I vote for closing the migrated one. It might have been asked many years ago on StackOverflow, but it's new here.

Edit: I see that the "native" question has been merged into the migrated one. I think this was a bad decision: the migrated question has a lot more votes, but its answers aren't really correct. It also has a bunch of "me too" answers that aren't adding any value. As I've commented, I don't think such a highly-voted question should have been migrated in the first place, because there's very little we can do to correct its problems.

Comment: Odd: when I voted to close-as-dupe the migrated question just now, it didn't look like anyone else had voted to close it yet, but there was already a suggested duplicate ("other users chose this question..."), so I thought it was a simultaneous-voting issue. But then after I submitted my vote, the count stood at 1, and remained at 1 even after refreshing the page.

Comment: I've voted to **close** the migrated one in favour of the ELU one, because it has a lot of votes for what ELU obviously consider to be *the wrong answer* (we nearly all agree both plurals are valid; the StackOverflow voters nearly all think only *indices* is valid).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Sorry, I can see now that my answer isn't as clear as it could be. I agree with you, and I'm editing to try to make this obvious.

Comment: Yeah, I did it wrong. There doesn't appear to be an undo, either. Maybe a dev can fix it :-/

Comment: @nohat♦: Just join the party by making sure you personally have upvoted the "tolerant" ELU top answer, and downvoted any (mainly SO) ones saying *indexes* can only be valid as a verb form. Always assuming you're on the side of tolerance, of course!

Comment: @nohat Unmerging questions is pretty difficult. Can you simply clean up the answers now? Remove "me too" answers, convert poor answers to comments, that sort of thing. Alternatively, I can undo the migration on SO's end and leave the question closed there... and you can remove whatever answers got merged into the question to get back to more or less what you had before. I agree that migrating such an old question (and one in a relatively poor state at that) was not the best decision.